# LSTM model training accuracy and loss not changing

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am doing Sepsis Forecasting using Multivariate LSTM. The target variable is SepsisLabel. The time series data look like this where each row represent an hour, with 5864 patients  (P_ID = 1 means its 1 patient data):

| HR | O2Sat | Temp | SBP | DBP | Resp | Age | Gender | ICULOS | SepsisLabel | P_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 72.0 | 97.4 | 36.33 | 108.5 | 52.7 | 16.7 | 80 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 78.0 | 97.0 | 36.53 | 169.0 | 82.0 | 14.5 | 80 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 68.0 | 97.0 | 36.20 | 150.0 | 71.0 | 14.0 | 80 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 1 |
| 70.0 | 97.0 | 36.21 | 149.0 | 71.0 | 14.0 | 80 | 0 | 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 67.0 | 98.0 | 36.11 | 157.0 | 73.0 | 14.0 | 80 | 0 | 5 | 1 | 1 |
| 73.0 | 98.0 | 36.18 | 162.0 | 78.0 | 15.0 | 80 | 0 | 6 | 1 | 1 |
| 69.0 | 99.0 | 36.63 | 156.0 | 73.0 | 13.0 | 80 | 0 | 7 | 1 | 1 |
| 70.0 | 100.0 | 36.00 | 167.0 | 79.0 | 12.0 | 80 | 0 | 8 | 1 | 1 |
| 78.0 | 98.0 | 37.13 | 177.0 | 79.0 | 17.0 | 80 | 0 | 9 | 0 | 2 |
| 73.0 | 98.0 | 36.78 | 152.0 | 71.0 | 13.5 | 80 | 0 | 10 | 0 | 2 |
| 79.5 | 96.5 | 37.17 | 185.0 | 94.0 | 23.2 | 80 | 0 | 11 | 0 | 2 |
| 73.0 | 96.0 | 36.72 | 190.0 | 96.0 | 24.0 | 80 | 0 | 12 | 0 | 2 |
| 101.0 | 95.0 | 37.13 | 188.0 | 91.0 | 26.5 | 80 | 0 | 13 | 0 | 2 |
| 88.0 | 95.0 | 37.56 | 145.0 | 68.0 | 24.0 | 80 | 0 | 14 | 1 | 2 |
| 92.0 | 95.0 | 37.23 | 172.0 | 81.0 | 24.0 | 80 | 0 | 15 | 1 | 2 |

The code:

```
X = df.drop('SepsisLabel',axis=1)
y = df[['SepsisLabel']]
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=42)
# reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
x_train = np.array(x_train).reshape(x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1)
x_test = np.array(x_test).reshape(x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], 1)
# Model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (10,1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(100, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(50,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics = ['accuracy'])
loss_plot = PlotLossesKeras()
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=15, batch_size=64, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True, callbacks = [loss_plot])
```

The Results:
[image: Loss and accuracy of model training]

```
accuracy
    training             (min:    0.899, max:    0.900, cur:    0.900)
    validation           (min:    0.900, max:    0.900, cur:    0.900)
Loss
    training             (min:    0.100, max:    0.101, cur:    0.100)
    validation           (min:    0.100, max:    0.100, cur:    0.100)
```

I initially ran 500 epochs but the result was same. Here, I used 15 epochs.
How I can improve the model and get the best results? Open for critiques and suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: I spot several problem. First, your data shape `(10, 1)` seems wrong. You have 10 time steps but only single one feature? Second, wrong loss function. `SepsisLabel` is a binary label, so you should consider loss function like cross entropy, precision or recell, etc, instead of `mse` (mean square error). If it is still not working, just try fitting a dense netowrk instead of LSTM to begin. Also, a small learning rate may help.

Comment: What should be the shape of the data with timesteps and features?

Comment: `features` should be 10 since you have 10 features: HR, O2Sat, ..., PID. `time steps` should be any number larger or equal than 1, you should determine it. You may see this example of predicting time series using LSTM: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#data_windowing

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same code to reproduce the error. But I got this output.

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics = ['accuracy'])

from livelossplot import PlotLossesKeras
loss_plot = PlotLossesKeras()
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=8, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True, callbacks = [loss_plot])
```

Output:

```
accuracy
    training             (min:    0.333, max:    0.778, cur:    0.778)
    validation           (min:    0.000, max:    1.000, cur:    0.333)
Loss
    training             (min:    0.169, max:    0.522, cur:    0.251)
    validation           (min:    0.179, max:    0.570, cur:    0.262)
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 473ms/step - loss: 0.2506 - accuracy: 0.7778 - val_loss: 0.2622 - val_accuracy: 0.3333
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f8c22ee4910>
```

Comment: Did you used the same model as mine?

Comment: Yes the same model.

Comment: Well I guess you used only this data I provided in this question. I have a lot more data. Anyhow, I will play with batch size and see what I can get.